# How to setup a card view in a corner

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, cardscrollview

I have an activity currently setup where there is a camera preview setup in a surface view. I am looking to implement a card view that scrolls similar to this: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui-widgets

The cards will show information regarding the images being looked at. Any idea how to have the card scroll concept implemented such that it takes up the upper right corner of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CardScrollView` is a basic Android view and it can be used in an xml layout file. I haven't tried what you are asking but I have managed to put an overlay over the `CardScrollView` so making it smaller and putting it in the corner could be possible as well.

I can't test it right now, but try out the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
      android:id="@+id/surface_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.glass.widget.CardScrollView
      android:id="@+id/card_scroll_view"
      android:layout_width="120px"
      android:layout_height="90px"
      android:layout_gravity="top|right"
      android:layout_marginTop="5px"
      android:layout_marginRight="5px" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You can find more information on the `FrameLayout` here:

http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/